# PHP Going Multiple Directories Back Best Practice

Tags: php

I'm writing a php library for managing configurations of an application.

but the problem is anyone who uses my library will store their configuration files in `./config` folder of their project root directory.

e.g. `var/www/example.com/config/site.php`

and my library is installed in a sub directory of the project

i.e  `vendor/azi/config/src/Config.php`

To Load files from project root i am doing it this way

```
    if (!defined('PATH_TO_CONFIG_DIR')) {
        define('PATH_TO_CONFIG_DIR', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))) . "/config/");
    }
```

is it right
? Or It can be more efficient. Code suggestion will be helpful.

Github : https://github.com/azeemhassni/Config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting the `dirname` calls, according to the [documentation for `dirname`](http://www.php.net/dirname) you could call this as of PHP 7:

```
dirname(__FILE__, 5)
```

For supporting lower versions of PHP, you could write a `parentDirectory` function:

```
function parentDirectory($path, $levels) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++) {
        $path = dirname($path);
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Or just embed it inside your current code, without a specific function:

```
$configPath = __FILE__;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $configPath = dirname($configPath);
}
define('PATH_TO_CONFIG_DIR', $configPath . "/config/");
```